# Global and static array of double values

Tags: java, objective-c

I want to translate this java code into equal objective-c code

```
double[] pMatrix = {50,100,150};

double[][] mMatrix = {{0.5,0.4,0.1}};
```

In java I have this as class properties. So I need to be able to access them everywhere in my class. I tried to put that code in the header file but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C++ supports C/C++. So, you must define `extern double Matrix[];` in the header and you `double Matrix[] = {50,100,150};` in the .mm. Also, you can define the same values as static members of some class (C++) or return them via static public methods.

Comment: No need to drop into Objective-C++ -- this can be done pretty easily in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

```
in .h
NSArray *pMatrix;
in .m
pMatrix=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"50",@"100",@"150",nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need them within the class, you can declare it as a static variable:

```
// In the .m file:

static double pMatrix[] = {50,100,50};
static double mMatrix[][3] = {{0.5,0.4,0.1}};

@implementation MyClass

- (void)someMethod
{
    pMatrix[1] = 50;
}

@end
```